# How do I parse multiple cookies from Set-Cookie header?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, cookies

I'm trying to parse multiple cookies from the Set-Cookie header, I tried looking for a solution on the web but I lucked out.

This is the header string I'm trying to parse.

```
blacklisted_tags=; path=/,,locale=en; path=/,,login=UserName; path=/; expires=Thu, 04-May-2017 22:35:39 GMT,,pass_hash=06xdbf50dfddb67f04352673g85o2645d7399xv; path=/; expires=Thu, 04-May-2017 22:35:39 GMT,_session=BAh7CDoMdXNlcl9pZGkDgGMBOg9hi4X9W9uX2lkIiVhNTBmOWYxMWZmYWY4ZjE4MTc3NWUxZjEyZWNmNzU3ZCIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaHsGOgtub3RpY2UiGllvdSBhcmUgbm93IGxvZ2dlZCBpbgY6Kn7j4MkewY7CEY%3D--18f67a3aa5cd039a23521dbf8d6be84e2ad55vnd; domain=.website.com; path=/; HttpOnly
```

and this is how fiddler parses it

```
Set-Cookie: blacklisted_tags=; path=/
Set-Cookie: 
Set-Cookie: locale=en; path=/
Set-Cookie: 
Set-Cookie: login=UserName; path=/; expires=Mon, 17-Apr-2017 17:34:43 GMT
Set-Cookie: 
Set-Cookie: pass_hash=06xdbf50dfddb67f04352673g85o2645d7399xv; path=/; expires=Mon, 17-Apr-2017 17:34:43 GMT
Set-Cookie: _session=BAh7CDoMdXNlcl9pZGkDgGMBOg9hi4X9W9uX2lkIiVhNTBmOWYxMWZmYWY4ZjE4MTc3NWUxZjEyZWNmNzU3ZCIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaHsGOgtub3RpY2UiGllvdSBhcmUgbm93IGxvZ2dlZCBpbgY6Kn7j4MkewY7CEY%3D--18f67a3aa5cd039a23521dbf8d6be84e2ad55vnd; domain=.website.com; path=/; HttpOnly
```

I've tried this RegEx pattern but it didn't work either

```
(.*?)=(.*?)($|;|,(?! ))
```

Since I'm not that good with regex I was hoping someone would help me with the right pattern.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/LYF610400210/CookieParser or https://github.com/keyvan/CommaDelimitedCookieParser4DotNet

Comment: Could ypu please let know the URL with such a cookie container?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried CookieParser before and it didn't help as for the URL I don't think I can post it here since it's NSFW, however, you can google "Sankaku Channel" to get it. I'm working on a tool that downloads pictures from that image board and I need the cookies so that I can parse beyond page 50 (you'll get 404 without the cookies!).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the uri - just use `System.Net.CookieContainer`. Parsing cookies can be error prone but the `CookieContainer` can do it for you.

Comment: The CookieContainer returns only the first one (blacklisted_tags) and I think the null values are causing this problem (,,)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind guys I figured it out!

I wrote this little function which takes the Set-Cookie header from the response as a parameter and returns the value of the given cookie name.

```
private string CookieValue(string header, string name)
{
    Match M = Regex.Match(header, string.Format("{0}=(?<value>.*?);", name));
    return (M.ToString().Split('=')[1]);
}
```

How to use:

```
string passHash = CookieValue(Response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie], pass_hash);
```

If you think there's something wrong with this function please share your thoughts.

Comment: Is there any chance the value could contain a `;`? If yes, this will fail. Can you obtain a list of all `name`s before running the regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes the value will contain a semicolon `;` but you can use string remove/replace to delete and for you 2nd question check the usage code I posted above `Response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie]` this will return the cookies from the set-cookie header in the response (check the first code block in my question) but note that it only works when there's a single set-cookie header.

Comment: I meant to ask if the `;` can be inside the value, like "name=part1;par2;part3;" and you need `part1;par2;part3`. Your regex will extract just `part1`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well the cookies are separated by commas `,` but as you can the expires value has a comma as well after the day name `expires=Mon, 17-Apr-2017 17:34:43 GMT` and in this case, you would end up with `login=UserName; path=/; expires=Thu` as a cookie which is not valid and as I stated earlier I'm not so good with RegEx so the only solution for me was to retrieve all the value separately and rebuild the full cookie.

Comment: I will share my regex once my kids go to bed.

Answer (score 1):

The cookies are separated by comma, but the Expires-date also contains a comma. So I use this (Java) code:

```
public static final Pattern COOKIE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("((?:[^,]|, )+)");

protected List<HttpCookie> parseCookieString(String setCookieHeaderValue)   {
    
    List<HttpCookie> parsed = new ArrayList<>();
    if (StringUtils.startsWith(setCookieHeaderValue, "[") && StringUtils.endsWith(setCookieHeaderValue, "]")) {

        List<String> stringList = parseCookieArray(removeFirstAndLastChar(setCookieHeaderValue));
        for (String string2 : stringList) {
            parsed.addAll(parseCookie(string2));
        }
    }
    else {
        parsed = parseCookie(setCookieHeaderValue);
    }
    return parsed;
}

private List<HttpCookie> parseCookie(String cookieString)
{
    try {
        return HttpCookie.parse(cookieString);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {

        LOG.error("Recieved cookie could not be parsed. Skipping:" + cookieString);
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

}

protected List<String> parseCookieArray(String string)
{
    List<String> cookieStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    String removeFirstAndLastChar = removeFirstAndLastChar(string);
    Matcher matcher = COOKIE_PATTERN.matcher(removeFirstAndLastChar);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        cookieStrings.add(matcher.group());
    }
    return cookieStrings;

}

protected String removeFirstAndLastChar(String string)
{
    return string.substring(1, string.length() - 1);
}
```